# How can i switch the stream I am listening to in a streambuilder in Dart?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, stream, google-cloud-firestore

Basically when the page first loads i want to use 1 stream that queries by geolocation but checks for documents where variable socialVisible is true, and then when the user clicks on a button to switch, i want the stream to instead still query by geolocation but now checks the documents with the field profVisible.

In theory this is very simple, whenever the corresponding button is pressed i set the state so that socialPressed=true and profPressed=false and then inside the streambuilder i used ternary operators to decide which stream should be used based on the truth values of socialPressed and profPressed.

However, this only works on the first click, the initial value of socialPressed is true so the initial stream is the social one and then when i click to go to the prof one it switches streams successfully. However after this time when i try to go back to social all the documents from prof remain instead of being replaced by social? This happens even when i switched the initial stream to prof, and i do not understand why this is happening?

```
StreamBuilder(
            stream:socialPressed==true?socStream:proStream,
            builder:
                (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshots) {
              if (!snapshots.hasData) {
                return Container(
                    alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else {
               return Container(
                    child: Container(
                      child: (snapshots.data.length == 0)
                          Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 2 / 3,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshots.data[index];
                          return UserTile('this is where i use the doc data')},
                          itemCount: snapshots.data.length,
                        ),),));}},)
```

This is the basic structure of my code, i have removed irrelevant info.

EDIT:
Button callback code was requested:

```
 FloatingActionButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0))),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    likeType='social';
                    socialPressed=!socialPressed;
                  });
                },
                elevation: 0,
                heroTag: 'socialButton',
                backgroundColor: socialPressed==false?Colors.grey[100]:Color(0xFFe0bdff),
                child: Icon(
                  Entypo.drink,
                  color: Color(0xFF8803fc),
                ),
              ),
              FloatingActionButton(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(16.0))),
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    likeType='prof';
                    socialPressed=!socialPressed;
                  });
                },
                elevation: 0,
                heroTag: 'profButton',
                backgroundColor: socialPressed==true?Colors.grey[100]:Color(0xFFb9ebe9),
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 30,
                    ),
                    Icon(
                      FontAwesome.graduation_cap,
                      color: Color(0xFF096664),
                    ),
                  ],

                ),
              ),
```

Comment: use one of `*Map()` methods (i would start with `switchMap()`) from [Observable](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable-class.html)

Comment: can you provide some example or pseudocode im not sure how i would implement this

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Observable/switchMap.html

Comment: i have used that, it worked for that case still have another bug though but if you add an answer for switchmap ill accept the answer as solved

Answer (score 0):

What logic do you use to set the state? It seems like you’re using two variables, `socialPressed` and `profPressed`. If you only have two states, I would consider using only one variable.

Without your code, we can only speculate as to what is going wrong. But this should work in the onPressed callback of your button:

```
onPressed: () => setState(() { socialPressed = !socialPressed; })
```

Comment: Yeah i was initially using two variables, but yes i originally thought the logic of setting the truth values of the variables was causing this but this isnt the case. I even created two streambuilders and depending on the truth value of socialPressed and profPressed the corresponding one was used. What happened was when i clicked on prof button the print statement inside that streambuilder code block execute and vice verse but yet the stream did not change. I dont know is there a rule about changing streams do i need to like stop listening to the stream? I have tried just 1 variable, didn work

Comment: It would help if you could edit your question to include your onPressed callback

Comment: okay i added the code and i added your recommendation, but again ive already tested that program entered the correct codeblock using the variables but failed to use the correct stream.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue. I am using RX Dart and tried to switch streams based on a boolean variable.

I was initially using PublishSubject for my stream. Switching to Behaviour Subject solved the issue for me. At this moment I don't have sufficient knowledge on why this works but would try to explore it further and edit here if possible.

Previous code :

```
final _activeOrdersFetcher = PublishSubject<OrderListModel>();
final _completedOrdersFetcher = PublishSubject<OrderListModel>();

StreamBuilder<OrderListModel>(
      stream: isActive
          ? _ordersBloc.getActiveOrders
          : _ordersBloc.getCompletedOrders
```

New Code Change :

```
final _activeOrdersFetcher = BehaviorSubject<OrderListModel>();
final _completedOrdersFetcher = BehaviorSubject<OrderListModel>();
```